# How to handle multiple one-to-zero-or-one relationships of the same entity type?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, primary-key

As I understand it EF6 implements one-to-zero-or-one relationships are projected into the database by sharing the same ID on the related entities

The [tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) says:

> A one-to-zero-or-one relationship happens when a primary key of one
>   table becomes PK & FK in another table in a relational database such
>   as SQL Server. So, we need to configure the above entities in such a
>   way that EF creates the Students and StudentAddresses tables in the DB
>   and makes the StudentId column in Student table as PrimaryKey (PK) and
>   StudentAddressId column in the StudentAddresses table as PK and
>   ForeignKey (FK) both.

So if a `Website` has an optional `WebsitePage`, I might have this:

```
public class Website
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual WebsitePage Page { get; set; }
}


public class WebsitePage
{
    [Key, ForeignKey( nameof( Website ) )]
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public virtual Website Website { get; set; }
}
```

But what if I want multiple optional pages, like this?

```
public class Website
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual WebsitePage AboutPage { get; set; }
    public virtual WebsitePage ServicesPage { get; set; }
    public virtual WebsitePage CaseStudyPage { get; set; }
}


public class WebsitePage
{
    [Key, ForeignKey( nameof( Website ) )]
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public virtual Website Website { get; set; }
}
```

It could be that my googling is substandard today, but I haven't been able to find any examples of this online, or here on SO.

Am I missing something, or is my understanding flawed?

Comment: Introduce your foreign relationships with explicit `Id` properties, not just providing navigational properties. For example, beside `AboutPage` property, add `public int? AboutPageId { get; set; }`; it must be nullable. `ForeignKey` attribute might not be needed (I'm, not sure). I'm not working with .NET Framework anymore, but I remember this worked for me.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, thank you.  My leap of understanding was that I need to put the `XxxPageId` FK on the `WebsitePage` model (as opposed to putting the `WebsiteId` FK on the `WebsitePage` model). Because otherwise the `Website` has no way of knowing which page id maps to each of the page properties.

Comment: If you want to put it as an answer I will mark it as such.

Comment: Why not just a `WebsitePages` collection?

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox Please see the updated answer and let me know which one is what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially I misunderstood the title of the relationship you wanted to implement. One-to-zero-or-one relationships can't be done when we have multiple references of one model in another. What you asked for is a one-to-many relationship; on one side we have 1 `WebsitePage` object, and on the other hand, we have `n` related `Website` objects which can have 1-3 `WebsitePage`s (please see comments). For that, you can use **Nullable Foreign Keys**.
Provide nullable ID properties beside navigation ones:

```cs
public class Website
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public int? AboutPageId { get; set; }
  public virtual WebsitePage AboutPage { get; set; }

  public int? ServicesPageId { get; set; }
  public virtual WebsitePage ServicesPage { get; set; }

  public int? CaseStudyPageId { get; set; }
  public virtual WebsitePage CaseStudyPage { get; set; }
}


public class WebsitePage
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

`WebsiteId` in `WebsitePage` model is not necessary. See [EF6 built-in conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/conventions/built-in).

You can also use Fluent API too, like what they did on that tutorial you linked.

**Edit:** If you want each page to belong to only one website, you might need to separate your models and use an intermediate model:

```cs
public class Website
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public virtual IList<WebsitePage> WebsitePages { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  //public PageType Type { get; set; }

  public virtual IList<WebsitePage> WebsitePages { get; set; }
}

public class WebsitePage
{
  [Key, ForeignKey(nameof(Page))]
  public int PageId { get; set; }
  public virtual Page Page { get; set; }

  public int WebsiteId { get; set; }
  public virtual Website Website { get; set; }
}
```

`PageId` can't be duplicate, and each record will need a `WebsiteId`; each page will belong to only one website (if any). It's tested with .NET Core 3.1/EF Core 2.2.

Again, you might be able to use only two models (`Website` and `Page`) and Fluent API to specify how the many-to-many relationship between them must prevent the duplication.

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: @GertArnold Not the exact sample code. But yeah. I used to have a simple base class with different properties related to users who did different actions on instances of child classes; `CreatorId`, `LastEditorId`, `LastReviewerId`, etc. There must be a nullable foreign key for each of these properties. That's how I did it. I'm not sure if it'll work with EF Core. Please let me know if there's something wrong.

Comment: Well, please do test this. (And in general: before posting code). I'm surprised it's accepted. It creates three 1-n relationships.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but my response was based on the last version of your answer. It's still three 1:n associations. The correct answer would have been: multiple 1:0..1 relationships to one type of entity can't be done in EF6. Your model could be an *alternative*, albeit not really appealing because one page can't be enforced to belong to exactly one site.

Comment: @GertArnold I probably misunderstood what the author wanted. As you said, actual one-to-zero-or-one relationships can't be implemented when we have multiple references of one model in another one. I'll update the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Mrmowji, your first answer achieved exactly what I was trying to do, so thank you very much.  GertArnold you helped me to see that I should perhaps approach the design in a different way, so thank you also.